# defining a State' monad which counts the Gets, Puts, Bind and Returns done on it

Tags: haskell, state

I'm trying to define a State monad State' in Haskell

```
newtype State' s a = State' { runState' :: (s, Counts) -> (a, s, Counts) }
```

Counts tracks the number of binds, returns gets and put done on it

```
data Counts = Counts {
binds   :: Int,
returns :: Int,
gets    :: Int,
puts    :: Int
} deriving (Eq, Show)

instance Monoid Counts where
mempty  = Counts 0 0 0 0
mappend (Counts x1 x2 x3 x4) (Counts y1 y2 y3 y4) = Counts (x1+y1) (x2+y2) (x3+y3) (x4+y4)
```

I have managed to define the return and >>= for this new monad as such

```
    return x = State' f
            where f = \(s, count) -> (x,s,count <> oneReturn

st >>= k = State' (\(s, count) -> let (x,s',count') = runState' st (s, count) in runState' (k x) (s',count' <> oneBind))
```

However, I am unable to define a get and put for this State'
They need to do exactly the same as the put and get of State, however they also need to increment count by onePut and oneGet (constants containing one get and one put)

Can anyone help me figure out how to best define the get and put for State'?

Comment: You can't count the number of binds and returns whilst satisfying the monad laws.  `m >>= return` should be equal to `m` according to the laws.

Comment: @TomEllis good point, but what is "equal"? Free monad `m >>= return` also doesn't construct structure equal to `m`, only adds "layers".

Comment: `Control.Monad.Free` does not add a layer but `operational` does.  This is one of the reasons I prefer `Free`, although it's not completely clear, as you say, that a rigid interpretation of equality is necessarily helpful in all cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems `get` is just like `return`, but supplies `s` instead of `x`.

```
get = State' $ \(s, count) -> (s, s, count <> oneGet)
```

Then `put` is also just like `return`, but sets new `s`.

```
put s' = State' $ \(s, count) -> ((), s', count <> onePut)
```

Comment: You forgot to put brackets around your lamda function, apart from that, you are completly correct

Comment: Perhaps you could wrap it into a `newtype` implementing `MonadState` (either as a monad or a monad transformer), so that you can use it wherever somebody uses the state monad.

Comment: @LordofTurtles I don't know what you mean. `$` is enough, and the expression to the right of `->` is the body of lambda.

Comment: @PetrPudlák good idea, but possibly the comment goes to the post, not this answer

Comment: The $'s weren't there when I added my first comment